# Как правильно писать тег BR?

Tags: html, html5, php

Возник вопрос по тегу `br`. Как следует его правильно писать: `<br>`, `</br>`, или `<br />`?

Comment: @XenK, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В зависимости от спецификации: для DOCTYPE HTML правильно будет `<br>`, для DOCTYPE XHTML - `<br />`. Для XHTML характерно в одинарных тегах ставить слэш перед закрывающий скобкой: `<br />, <hr />, <input />` и т.д.

Написание `</br>` - неверно, т.к. BR - одинарный тег, а слэш после открывающей скобки - только для закрывающих дескрипторов.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше писать <br/>, но если напишите <br>, браузер вас поймет.

Answer (score -5):

Лучше писать - `<br>` !!!
Это экономичнее :)
+ у меня сложилось подозрение, что Все браузеры, в будущем НЕ откажутся от поддержки `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` (скорее наоборот, становится стандартом - навечно) , а `<... xhtml>` - вроде как устаревающий тип и все по старинке полагаются на авось (аля 100% совместимость с браузерами и стандартами 2000 года).

А сейчас 2018-й год !!!
И всем браузерам этот мусорный(именно так для них) слеш нахрен ненужен !!!
А все генераторы мусора (хтмл редакторы), подтвержают свой статус - генераторов МУСОРА, поскольку до сих пор продолжают везде лепить этот слеш в одинарные теги - br, img, inp, и др.

Юзайте только - `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
Вас все поймут, а процессоры скажут спасибо (нет мусорных знаков - быстрее парсинг текста)

P.S.
А вот и подтверждение:
Тег `<br>` - РЕКОМЕНДОВАН в [PHP5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)
и взят в будущее !!!
Старые варианты - `<br/>` и `<br />` (вместе со старыми браузерами, а именно IE 6) - можно отправить на пенсию и - не МУСОРИТЬ в своих html страницах. Особенно если они полностью ваши (не паранойная СMS или полностью Ваша CMS).

**Обновление**

Да не надо ничего ЗУБРИТЬ !!!
это как 2+2 !

```
<br> <hr> <input> <img> <meta>
```

ОДИНАРНЫЕ !!! им ненужен закрывающий тег, они не предусмотрены спецификой этих тегов. И тем более всякие мусорные слеши (в теле). Это HTLM и все популярные и современные CMS только под HTML (других не встречал)

Я это понял в первый день (10 лет назад) !!! Просто Вам лично самому не противно видеть `<br />` (4+3 долба по клаве) или `<br>` (всего 4 долба).
Далее берём парсер (обработчик текста). Если вы рубите, что ему проще обрабьать первый вид, а не два других - то печалька (за вас).
Даже разработчики HTML это поняли и уже открыто рекомендуют использовать ТОЛЬКО `<br>`.

Терь понятно почему очень многие сайты такие мегатонные (сотни килобайт мусорного кода). Пихают всё сразу и везде, не задумываясь о том, а нужно ли всё это нам посетителям.
Нам нужна моментальная загрузка страниц, ответ на вопрос или найденный товар и умеренная реклама (только на полях, а не между строк). Но как заглянешь на страницу такого мегатонника, так сразу видишь куеву тучу ненужных (мне) подгрузок (яваскрипта, шрифтов, css с внешних серверов, которые в таких раскладах - не кешируются) и их приходится обрабатывать моему браузеру на моём компе (тратятся мои ресурсы - НИЗАЧТО).

**Обновление 2**

Вот когда мне нужно будет, чтото перевести(портировать) в XHTML. Это мой скрипт сделает автоматически (добавит слеш). Другим на моих страницах делать нечего и под их унификацию подстраиваться не обязан (!!!) и другим не советую.

Comment: Для `<br>` нужно где-то хранить (а разработчику — зазубривать наизусть) список тегов, в котором будет записано, что br является одиночным. Поэтому лучше писать именно `<br/>` — так сразу же видно, что тег является одиночным, и ничего зазубривать не надо. Кроме того, остаётся совместимость с XHTML (он вообще-то применяется далеко не только в браузерах, знаете ли)

Comment: Есть такая вещь как документы, сервисы, обмен данными и они работают хорошо тогда, когда все унифицировано. Есть язык, который с этим хорошо справляется, называется XML и который обладает строгими правилами, на его основе сделан XHTML. Изначально HTML тоже делали на основе XML. Но люди делали очень много ошибок, браузеры стали не ругаться, а просто исправлять ОШИБКИ которые вы допустили и поощрять делать их дальше. Поэтому да, тег без закрывающего слеша, это просто ошибка которую стандартизировали в HTML5. И да, если вы пишите со слешем, то потом гораздо проще превратить документ в XHTML5.

Comment: Если вы хотите что–то добавить, пожалуйста, обновляйте ваш исходный ответ, а не публикуйте новые. Для внесения улучшающей правки нажмите на ссылку «править» под телом ответа.

Comment: В html6 собираются убрать непонятные простому парсеру конструкции типа одиночных тегов без закрытия, типа `<br>`. Что бы язык стал наиболее просто обрабатываться даже простыми парсерами.

Comment: Правда ссылку где я это читал найти не могу.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин странные слухи. Я вот, наоборот, вижу обратный процесс.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну да, сначала придумали XHTML а потом HTML5 и обнулили идеи XHTML... но по сути идея правильная, что бы обычными XML парсерами можно было читать HTML код, без каких-то дополнительных ухищрений.